# Correlated subquery where data is not in a table

Tags: php, mysql, correlated-subquery

I am using MySql and have a situation which is a lot like a correlated subquery except that the data in the inner query is not in the database - but in a PHP session.

If all the data were in the database, the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE (tableA.valueA && (
SELECT valueB FROM tableB WHERE tableB.id = tableA.id));
```

My problem is that I have no tableB.  Instead I have a PHP array.  How can I inject the array into the query?  Should I attempt to create a temporary table somewhere?  Or perhaps I should be trying to declare the array as a variable?

The information in the PHP array is specific to each user and changes rapidly.  Also, there will be lots of queries so performance is a consideration.

Comment: MySQL has no concept of arrays, and even `FIND_IN_SET` would work with positional markers, and not 'named' entries like `tableB.id` for a specific one. A temporary table seems indeed a nice workaround for this. Although, if your actual array is not that big, you just might want to fetch all those `WHERE tableB.id = tableA.id`'s, and do the `valueA && valueB` filtering in PHP itself. If you go for a temporary table, just make it a `JOIN` instead of a subquery.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken.  Why don't you post this as an answer?  I am happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments from Wrikken above - I have made this a temporary table and it seems to be a fine solution.